# Ember Data deleteRecord() followed by rollback() - how to make object reappear in list?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

In a controller:

```
    actions: {

        selectDelete: function(note) {
            console.log('selectDelete', note);
            note.deleteRecord();
            note.save().then(
                function success() {
                    console.log('Deleted successfully');
                }, function failure() {
                    console.log('Delete error before',
                      this.get('isDeleted'), this.get('isDirty'); //true, true
                    // note.transitionTo('loaded.saved'); //also has same effect
                    note.rollback();
                    console.log('Delete error after',
                      this.get('isDeleted'), this.get('isDirty'); //false, false
                }
            );
        },
    }
```

In a template:

```
{{#each note in model.notes}}
<li>
    <span>{{note.text}}</span>
    <span {{action 'selectDelete' note}}>[Delete]</span>
</li>
{{else}}
No Notes
{{/each}}
```

Now when I click on the `[Delete]` span, the `selectDelete` action gets triggered, with the following output:

```
Delete error before true true
Delete error after false false
```

... which means that the rollback was successful, and the record has indeed been un-deleted.

However, while calling `deleteRecord()` updates the DOM to remove the part that represents the deleted record,
calling `rollback()` appears to revert the changes to the record in memory, but fails to revert the changes in the DOM.

How can I ensure that `rollback()` triggers this change?

Alternatively, is there a way to alter the default behaviour such that `deleteRecord()` does not trigger a change in the DOM,
and instead leaves it unchanged, deferring that change until the `success` callback is called?
(That way a reverting changes to the DOM will not be necessary)

Comment: Everything works as expected when using this.store.find('user')  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dibake/1/edit. Based on my jsbin could you replicate your case (setup specific models, mock response...), I guess the problem could be a bug when iterating a hasMany relationship.

Comment: @ppcano `deleteRecord()` does *not* actually delete the record or send a HTTP request to the server. This only happens upon `save()`. Why do you invoke `deleteRecord()` in the `del` action, but invoke `save()` in the `restore` action?

Comment: I was just testing your use case.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the record was removed from the route's model *(aka vislble list)*, but not from the store *(cache for visible & non-visible models.)*

Try pushing it again to `route.model` manually.

```
route.get('model').pushObject(note);
```

Comment: You may also want to store it's location before deleting, so that you can push it back to the same place.